# "the readable size is 'x*4, but 8' bytes may be writted/read" with arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, mfc

So I have a program, which helps me finding a cycles in graph by adjacency matrix. I have done everything, except output.

**Realization**

So, upon clicking exectute button, from masked edit control, an number up to 99 taken to for making a size of some arrays. Then I am creating 2d array **arr to fill it with zeros, and after that via for I fill info from text written in normal edit control. After this step I fill vector with edges from that array and doing DFS for that graph.

**Now about problem**

Like I said, I have 2d array. The whole procedure of filling it with zeros:

```
int **arr;
arr = new int* [x];
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    arr[i] = new int[x];
}

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

And with the next procedure (taking adjacency matrix from edit control) lies the warning #1:

```
int i = 0, j;
int lpos = 0;
for (CString line = s.Tokenize(_T("\r\n"), lpos); lpos > 0; line = s.Tokenize(_T("\r\n"), lpos))
{   
    j = 0;
    int cpos = 0;
    for (CString cell = line.Tokenize(_T(" "), cpos); cpos > 0; cell = line.Tokenize(_T(" "), cpos))
    {
        int num;
        num = _wtoi(cell);
        arr[i][j] = num;
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

`Warning    C6386   Buffer overrun while writing to 'arr[i]':  the writable size is 'x*4' bytes, but '8' bytes might be written.`

And before making output, I also put in another vector cycles and it also has warning #2:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= edges; i++) {
        if (mark[i] != 0) {
        int k = mark[i];
        cycles[k].push_back(i);
    }
}
```

`Warning C6385   Reading invalid data from 'mark':  the readable size is 'x*4' bytes, but '8' bytes may be read.`

The problem is, when I tested output (adjacency matrix 7x7, all filled with 1), it catches an exception for those 2 pieces, which is being warnings. The exceptions is: `Exception thrown at 0x00007FF6DD63AD7A in CTabControl.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000FDFDFDFD.`

**What I tried**

For now, I tried to use make_unique pointer as an alterative for `*` pointer on mark, which was declared previously like this: `int *mark = new int[x];` (changed to `auto mark = make_unique<int[]>(x);`). After change, there is a new error appear: 
    `E0413  no suitable conversion function from "std::unique_ptr<int [], std::default_delete<int []>>" to "int *" exists`

It points out to the function, where I use mark array: `dfs_cycle(1, 0, color, mark, par, cyclenumber);`

The function declared like this:

```
void dfs_cycle(int u, int p, int color[], int mark[], int par[], int& cyclenumber)
{
 // ........
}
```

What can I do here to fix that?

**EDIT**

I think I found the problem, yet for now I can't find a solution. So, when the text is being read from text box, where adjacency matrix is, I am filling up the array with the contents of tokenized text. Here's how I am doing it:

```
int i = 0, j; int lpos = 0;
for (CString line = s.Tokenize(_T("\r\n"), lpos); lpos > 0; line = s.Tokenize(_T("\r\n"), lpos)){   
        j = 0;
        int cpos = 0;
        for (CString cell = line.Tokenize(_T(" "), cpos); cpos > 0; cell = line.Tokenize(_T(" "), cpos))
        {       
            int num;
            num = _wtoi(cell);
            arr[i][j] = num;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
}
```

When I try to make arr a 2d vector, I stumbled upon "out of range" error. So, that means I have to somehow tokenize my text and put it in array. I haven't figured out how.

Comment: Is it possible when you run your code that the value of `x` is zero or one? This is what the warnings are hinting at. If that's the case, then change the size in *all* your `new` operations from `[x]` to `[max(2,x)]`.

Comment: Doesn't change anything here. But noted about it, the graph can't be represented with adjacency matrix with only 1 vertex. But the error itself appears when the cycles exist.

Comment: You have shown some parts of your code, but it's not clear what you are doing. Please make minimum example which can be compiled and reproduce the errors and warnings. And state the desired behavior. Also consider using 2-d vector with `std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec;`, you can pass the vector (by reference) to another function.

Comment: I think I got nailed down the problematic place. I'll edit in a few my main thread.